# Python range function - stop step is function

Tags: python, function, loops

Simple question that likely due to keywords, lead to an explanation on the function itself rather than clarification on whether or not the following is the case:

When using the range function to loop, with a function as the stop step, 
e.g.

```
for item in range(some_function()):
    #do something
```

is the result of the function call stored for use or evaluated at each step?

I'd imagine its the former but it agitates that I can't confirm.

Comment: Have you checked the python docs for [version 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) and [version 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)? You should specify which python version you're using.

Comment: I did spend some time doing exactly that, I was just looking in the wrong place. docs for the [for](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) statement should have been the place I looked as @BrenBarn illustrated.

Comment: FWIW, you can easily test stuff like this. Eg, `def f(): print('in f'); return 5`. Now see what `for i in range(f()):` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing special about `range` here.  The behavior is defined in [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

> The expression list is evaluated once

The "expression list" is the part after the `in` (i.e., `range(some_function())` in your example).  No matter what is there, it is only evaluated once.